# Flutter merge two firestore streams into a single stream

Tags: firebase, merge, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, rxdart

I simply want to perform an 'OR' operation and get the both results of two queries into one stream.

Here's my code with a single stream

```
 StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance
        .collection('list')
        .where('id', isEqualTo: 'false')
        .orderBy('timestamp')
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          ],
        );
      if (snapshot.data.documents.length == 0)
        return const Center(
          child: Text(
            "Not Available",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        );
      return ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        key: Key(randomString(20)),
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListCard(snapshot.data.documents[index]);
        },
      );
    }),
```

Instead of a single stream now I want to feed two stream to the same stream builder.

I tried StreamGroup but it's not working since Widgets rebuild

```
StreamGroup.merge([streamOne, streamTwo]).asBroadcastStream();
```

I tried followed method also

```
 Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> searchResult()  {
List<Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>>> streamList = [];

Firestore.instance
    .collection('room-list')
    .where('id', isEqualTo: 'false')
    .snapshots()
    .forEach((snap) {
  streamList.add(Observable.just(snap.documents));
});

Firestore.instance
    .collection('room-list')
    .where('id', isEqualTo: 'pending')
    .snapshots()
    .forEach((snap) {
  streamList.add(Observable.just(snap.documents));
});

var x = Observable.merge(streamList)
    .scan<List<DocumentSnapshot>>((acc, curr, i) {
  return acc ?? <DocumentSnapshot>[]
    ..addAll(curr);
});
return x;
}
```

Here I get the error there should be at least a single stream to merge. Its because Observable.merge(streamList) is called before items are added to streamList.

I simply want to get the both results of two queries into one stream.

Comment: Can you chain the `.where()` calls?

Comment: You can chain and it will become an AND operator not OR that's the issue.. A simple OR in where could solve this, but such option not available

Comment: @PraneethDhanushkaFernando Did you manage to get around this issue?

Comment: @hadooper nope bro still struggling

Comment: I am having the same problem in the end what did you do to fix the issue

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214217/combine-streams-from-firestore-in-flutter (the linked one is older and has better answers)

Answer (score 7):

This should work.

```
//Change your streams here
    Stream<List<QuerySnapshot>> getData() {
        Stream stream1 = Firestore.instance.collection('list').where('id', isEqualTo: 'false').orderBy('timestamp').snapshots();
        Stream stream2 = Firestore.instance.collection('list').where('id', isEqualTo: 'true').orderBy('timestamp').snapshots();
        return StreamZip([stream1, stream2]);
      }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: getData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<QuerySnapshot>> snapshot1) {

            List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshotData =  snapshot1.data.toList();

            //copy document snapshots from second stream to first so querySnapshotData[0].documents will have all documents from both query snapshots
            querySnapshotData[0].documents.addAll(querySnapshotData[1].documents);

            if (querySnapshotData[0].documents.isEmpty)
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                ],
              );
            if (querySnapshotData[0].documents.length == 0)
              return const Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Not Available",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              );

            return new ListView(
                children: querySnapshotData[0].documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
                 // put your logic here. You will have access to document from both streams as "document" here
                  return new ListCard(document);
                }).toList()
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: @PraneethDhanushkaFernando please try this and let me know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: StreamZip cannot be used for this bro. It used to combined streams that belongs with each other like Title and Post

Comment: in that case you will need nested streambuilder

Comment: This worked for my particular case. I've been at it all day still I stumbled on your answer. Thanks @m-bhole, from the Future :)

Comment: make sure to add async to your dependencies

Comment: It has not worked for me. When there is another event in one of the Streams, StreamBuider was not called.
What worked for me: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23173
Rx.merge + scan

Comment: What if you have different Types instead of a List?

Answer (score 5):

I was also trying to combine two streams from firestore (as querying does not support OR) and went about it like this:

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';


Rx.combineLatest2(
   StreamQuerySnapshot1, //a snapshot from firestore
   StreamQuerySnapshot2, //another snapshot from firestore
   (var stream1, var stream2) {
    return [...stream1.docs, ...stream2.docs]; //Concatenated list
   }
)
```

This will emit changes no matter which streams is changing in contrast to other solutions I found which support emits only if both streams have changes.

Answer (score 3):

I used RxDart package to combine two streams as shown below

[RxDart - CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html)

```
final Stream<DocumentSnapshot> user = Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .document(firebaseUser.uid)
        .snapshots();

    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> cards =
        Firestore.instance.collection("cards").snapshots();

    CombineLatestStream.list([user, cards]).listen((data) {
      add(LoadedHomeEvent(
        data.elementAt(0),
        data.elementAt(1),
      ));
    });
```

Comment: You have used `CombineLatestStream....` then what is further code? Kindly share full of code so that other users and I can understand what is happening? Its just a request :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure why you’re using forEach and Observable.just().

You can just merge two firestore streams directly like:

Observable.merge([stream1, stream2]).pipe(combineStream);

Wherre stream1/2 is just your firestore snapshot.

Comment: From where does combineStream come?

Comment: Just create a new PublishSubject or StreamContoller for combineStream.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it failed. The issue since stream1 is a firestore querysnapshot when I tried to call merge it says i'm trying to merge an empty stream. It is because stream1 and stream2 are not initialized yet as they are waiting for firestore. How can i make sure stream1 and  sream2 are initialized before called merge?

Answer (score 2):

Well I am late, but just gonna put it out there.

You can add whereIn clause in your query like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("collection_name").where("field",whereIn:["false","true"]).snapshots();
```

Comment: This is Not Working at all!

Comment: They may have changed the methods.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is to use `MergeStream` from [RxDart](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/MergeStream-class.html)

```dart
Stream<QuerySnapshot> searchResult() {
  final falseRoomStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('room-list')
      .where('id', isEqualTo: 'false')
      .snapshots();

  final pendingRoomStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('room-list')
      .where('id', isEqualTo: 'pending')
      .snapshots();

  return MergeStream([falseRoomStream, pendingRoomStream]);
}
```