# Firebase real-time database to join two nodes in Flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I am using Flutter as Mobile front end framework and firebase realtime database as backend. I need to join two firebase nodes (say A and B). I added listeners to the node A to listen for realtime updates. How do I join node B and add the values from it to a single list created from node A? Node B can be read once as I dont need the realtime updates of it.

How can I achieve this in flutter?

Please advise.

Comment: The "nodes" you say are QuerySnapshots? like results from queries you did?

Comment: Yes they are Query snapshots.

Comment: See if this helps, I used it once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287717/flutter-merge-two-firestore-streams-into-a-single-stream

Comment: Thanks George. It looks like it is to merge two lists. But I am trying to get a list and query another another node using key from the list, get a value and add it to the same list, which is similar to left outer join in SQL queries.