# Cloud Firestore - How can I get a foreing key with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Events collection with these fields:

```
name: "Event 1",
description: "Description 1",
tags: [1, 4]
```

And in the Tags collection:

```
id: 1,
name: "Party Hard",
color: "red"
```

How can I concat these 2 collections and return something like this?

```
name: "Event 1",
description: "Description 1",
tags: [{
  name: "Party Hard",
  color: "red"
}, {
  name: "Open bar",
  color: "blue"
}]
```

Comment: If you're asking if Firestore can do the equivelant of a SQL joins that combine documents between collections, the answer is no.  You have to query each collection separately and combine the results in your app.

Comment: If what Doug wants is indeed what you're trying to do, also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65641342/combine-two-different-collections-of-firebase-in-flutter

Comment: Thanks, guys! I got it like this: https://i.ibb.co/HG62cRp/Captura-de-Tela-2023-04-16-a-s-22-27-02.png

Comment: @MaiconFurtado Can you post your solved issue as an answer so the other community members will also get help from that ?