# displaying data from different firestore collections

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm attempting display data from two diffrent collections within firestore , I treied to nest both streambuilds so i can particulary display the data as one stream , however I keep on getting the error `bad state field doesnt exist with doc snapshot` how can i fixing thus error , or is there another much more effective method i can use to display data from two diffrent collections in one class?

below is screenshot of the data(s) i want to display:
[image]
[image]

```
class OrderStream extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String route = "/Order";

  final CollectionReference meal =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("menu");
  final CollectionReference profile =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

  OrderStream({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: profile.snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
              return StreamBuilder(
                stream: meal.snapshots(),
                builder:
                    (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
                  if (!streamSnapshot.hasData) {
                    return const SizedBox(
                      height: 250,
                      child: Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                              streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
                          return Column(
                             children: [
                            Text( documentSnapshot['price'],)
                            Text( documentSnapshot['name'],)
                             

                           ]
                              ),
                            ),
                      }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Updated the code as your error

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening due to similar name for both snapshots.

The best way to check this is by renaming the snapshot for individual `Streambuilder()`.

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: profile.snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> profileStreamSnapshot) {
              return StreamBuilder(
                stream: meal.snapshots(),
                builder:
                    (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> mealStreamSnapshot) {
                  if (!streamSnapshot.hasData) {
                    //modified (renamed snapshot variable) code here
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge those two streams into 1 using library like `rxdart` which has [combineLatest2](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx/combineLatest2.html) method although you can also use something like [StreamZip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398215/20239914) to get the same effect.

I have used rxdart combineLatest2 as follows:

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';//import ⇐

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final CollectionReference profile =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
  final CollectionReference meal =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("menu");
  MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Rx.combineLatest2(profile.snapshots(), meal.snapshots(),
              (QuerySnapshot profileSnapshot, QuerySnapshot mealSnapshot) {
            return [...profileSnapshot.docs, ...mealSnapshot.docs];
          }),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return const SizedBox(
                height: 250,
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                      snapshot.data![index];
                  final Map<String, dynamic> data =
                      documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                  if (data.containsKey("price") && data.containsKey("name")) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [Text(data["price"]), Text(data["name"])],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container();
                  }
                },
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

You can also use `Stream.merge()` as follows:

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> mealsStream = meal.snapshots();
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> profilesStream = profile.snapshots();
//.. All that Scaffold stuff
stream: Stream.merge([mealsStream, profilesStream]),
```

Comment: although i get the idea , i found that it still gives the error of "bad state , documentsnapshot doesnt exist"

Comment: @Jabu Updated the code as your error