# How to add an OR condition to flutter Firebase queries

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add an `OR` condition to my flutter firebase query.

Here is my code but I want to check where `receiver_name` is equal to `kim` OR `sender_name` is equal to `kim`

```
StreamBuilder( 
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection("payments").where("receiver_name", isEqualTo: userActive).snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
 

  return Container ( child:ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    controller: ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: false),
    itemBuilder: (context, index){

      DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index];
```

Comment: I don't see a way to do this natively with the `cloud_firestore` package. You probably have to do 2 separate queries and you can combine the streams.

Comment: Thanks, I see, how do I go about combining streams after I got them?if you don't mind me asking

Comment: You can either follow one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214217/combine-streams-from-firestore-in-flutter)(probably the highest voted one, not the accepted) or maybe follow instructions [here](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams) to create/transform a stream

Answer (score 7):

**OR operator is now available in Firebase.**

Its can be achieved now by using `Filter.or`.
Follow this link for more details on it: [OR operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries)

For this you need Cloud Firestore version 24.4.5

in Flutter you need `cloud_firestore: ^4.5.0`

To query it, you have write like this:

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection("payments")
        .where(Filter.or(
            Filter("receiver_name", isEqualTo: "kim"),
            Filter("sender_name", isEqualTo: "kim")
               )).snapshots();
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: Since March 2023 OR conditions across multiple fields **are** possible on Firestore, as shown in the new documentation on [`OR` queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries). Be sure to check out the document, including the [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations_3) on queries that use OR clauses.

An example of the syntax for OR conditions:

```
snapshot = await db.collection('/76015089').where(
  Filter.or(
    Filter("name", isEqualTo: "John"),
    Filter("id", isNotEqualTo: "null"),
  )
).get();
print('Got ${snapshot.docs.length} documents');
for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
  print(' ${doc.id}: name=${doc.get("name")} id=${doc.get("id")}');
}
```

---

For this specific use-case, you can also consider this alternative solution:

#### Add an array of participants to each document

If you add an array field `participants` to your documents, with in it the UID fields of the sender and the receiver, you can then use an [`array-contains` query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) to get all payments in which the user was either the sender or the receiver.

To add a UID to such an array, be sure to use the [`array-union` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

```
documentRef.updateData({"participants": FieldValue.arrayUnion("uidOfUser")});
```

And then to query it, you'd use:

```
collectionRef.where('participants', arrayContains: "uidOfUser")
```

Comment: Filter.and  or Filter.or