# Flutter : How to get Stream Query with OR condition in [Firebase]

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement OR condition in flutter using the multiple `where();` method but this returns `AND` condition.

Following is my code for query

```
  Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getOrders() async { 
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Orders")
        .orderBy("timestamp")
        .where("isCredentialUploaded", isEqualTo: true),
        .where("isTransactionDone", isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

But this makes the AND Condition, like this

```
if(isCredentialUploaded && isTransactionDone)
```

**Is there any way I can get the OR condition in Firebase Firestore?**

***Result i want:***

```
if(isCredentialUploaded || isTransactionDone)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation of [Firebase & Flutter](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying) we notice that after using the query we must use `get()` instead of `snapshot()`.

Try this code:

```
Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getOrders() async { 
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("Orders")
    .orderBy("timestamp")
    .where("isCredentialUploaded", isEqualTo: true),
    .where("isTransactionDone", isEqualTo: true)
    .get();
}
```

Comment: Dear @Z.Ihab  I am talking about OR Conditions in firebase.

Comment: now i understand you, look at this is very helpful for you [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63092557/17170163)