# Either or condition in flutter firebase query in where condition

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use a OR condition in flutter firebase but it returns AND condition. I have try for a day

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Flight_Details")
        .where("Date", isEqualTo: widget.alanFilter)
        .where("From",isEqualTo: widget.fromAlanFilter)
        .where("To",isEqualTo: widget.toAlanFilter)
        .snapshots(),
```

Comment: OR condition is not supported, seems to be a duplicated question as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63092249/how-to-add-an-or-condition-to-flutter-firebase-queries

Answer (score 0):

I have using this and it working.....
The code block below retrieves data from a Firestore collection named 'templates' based on a certain condition. The 'uid' field of the documents is checked against a list of values that includes the 'doctorId' widget property and an empty string. The resulting data is returned as a stream of snapshots.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('templates')
    .where('uid', whereIn: [widget.doctorId, ''])
    .snapshots(),
```