# Flutter firebase select where or and orderby

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The new version cloud_firestore: ^4.5.1 allows filter by "or" and "and" by this way:

```
Future<List> getListModelos() async {
  List objetoList1 = [];
  Query<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReferenceObjetoList1 =
      db.collection('/modelos').where(
            Filter.and(
              Filter("name", isEqualTo: "John"),
              Filter("id", isEqualTo: "01"),
            ),
          );
  QuerySnapshot queryObjetoList1 = await collectionReferenceObjetoList1.get();
  queryObjetoList1.docs.forEach((documento) {
    objetoList1.add(documento.data());
  });
  return objetoList1;
}
```

I found this helpfull info here:
[How to add an OR condition to flutter Firebase queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63092249/how-to-add-an-or-condition-to-flutter-firebase-queries)

But, when trying "isEqualTo" + "isNotEqualTo" the query not returns nothing:

```
db.collection('/modelos').where(
            Filter.and(
              Filter("name", isEqualTo: "John"),
              Filter("id", isNotEqualTo: "null"),
            ),
          );
```

Is there any way or suggestion to query from Flutter to Firebase that allow "select where isEqual and isNotEqual"?

Comment: Do you really have a string value `"null"` in your database?

Comment: no, it's just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two most likely problem here is that this query requires a composite index, and those are not automatically created. If I run the query without creating an index, it logs this error:

> cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/_/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Clxwcm9qZWN0cy9wcm9qZWN0LTgwODAwNTkzMjUyODIwOTgxODQvZGF0YWJhc2VzLyhkZWZhdWx0KS9jb2xsZWN0aW9uR3JvdXBzLzc2MDE1MDg5L2luZGV4ZXMvXxABGggKBG5hbWUQARoGCgJpZBABGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAE

That link in there takes you directly to the Firestore console page to create the necessary index, with all details already filled out. All I had to do is click the button, and wait for the index to be created. Once the index has been created,  my query returns the documents where `name` is `"John"` and with an `id` field whose literal string value is not equal to `"null"`.

Comment: Great! I followed the steps given in your suggestion. It works!!!
I apreciate your answer very much. Regards.