# Flutter Firestore real-time pagination using multiple listeners streamed combined

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I want to create a pagination screen, using Bloc, from the Firestore database. The screen should update on document changes.

My `FirestoreProviderApi` receives fetch requests from the Bloc unit. After fetching the documents from Firestore, it sends them back to the Bloc using a `Stream`.

The `FirestoreProviderApi`:

```
  final _pollOverviewStreamController = BehaviorSubject<QuerySnapshot>();

  @override
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getOverviewPolls<QuerySnapshot>() =>
      _pollOverviewStreamController.asBroadcastStream().cast();

  @override
  Future<void> fetchFirstOverviewPolls() async {
    _overviewPollsRef.limit(5).snapshots().listen((querySnapshot) {
      _pollOverviewStreamController.add(querySnapshot);
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> fetchNextOverviewPolls() async {
    if (_pollOverviewStreamController.value.docs.isEmpty) return;

    final lastDoc = _pollOverviewStreamController.value.docs.last;
    _overviewPollsRef
        .startAfterDocument(lastDoc)
        .limit(5)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((querySnapshot) {
      _pollOverviewStreamController.add(querySnapshot);
    });
  }
```

**On document changes, I want to update my list of documents**.

Right now, whenever a change occurs, a new QuerySnapshot is appended to the Stream (instead of replacing the old one).
**Is there a way to combine multiple listeners to the same Stream, aggregating only the most up-to-date data?**

Comment: you can [combine multiple streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214217/combine-streams-from-firestore-in-flutter) into one stream that gives most recent data using [RxDart](https://codewithandrea.com/videos/rx-dart-by-example-combine-latest/).

Comment: [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html) is not a fit solution, since I'm always listening for document changes, while `CombineLatestStream` emits only if all Streams end.

Comment: Seems that what I'm looking for is not possible. I have found an alternative tutorial that explains how to solve it in a different way https://www.filledstacks.com/post/how-to-perform-real-time-pagination-with-firestore/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue solved.

I found good documentation of how to implement [real-time pagination using Firestore](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/how-to-perform-real-time-pagination-with-firestore/) (been implemented it, works like a charm).

Youtube implementation: [Flutter and Firestore real-time Pagination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1chV50D5BVU).

High-level steps:

1. Create a class-scoped **document list state** variable.
2. Stream each time **the whole list**.
3. Listen and iterate over snapshot changes, and **update/add documents to the main list**.
4. If the list is not empty, then **fetch from the last** document on the list.

### My implementation:

```
final List<DocumentSnapshot> _overviewPolls = [];

@override
  Future<void> fetchOverviewPolls(
      [int firstFetchLimit = 1, int nextFetchLimit = 1]) async {

    Query overviewPollsQuery = _overviewPollsRef.limit(firstFetchLimit);

    if (_overviewPolls.isNotEmpty) {
      overviewPollsQuery = overviewPollsQuery
          .startAfterDocument(_overviewPolls.last)
          .limit(nextFetchLimit);
    }

    overviewPollsQuery.snapshots().listen((querySnapshot) {
      if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (final doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
          int index = _overviewPolls.indexWhere((d) => d.id == doc.id);
          // if already exists - update poll
          if (index >= 0) {
            _overviewPolls[index] = doc;
          }
          // if new document - add poll
          else {
            _overviewPolls.add(doc);
          }
        }

        _pollOverviewStreamController.add(_overviewPolls);
      }
    });
  }
```

### Using orderBy

Note that **if you are using `orderBy`** on querying your snapshot, any update to the order's field **will cause a reordering of the whole list** of items. Moreover, in some cases, **it will fetch automatically more items** (since we are using a limit for each snapshot, and the list of items is reordered, some snapshots may need to fetch more items to fill its limitation).

Comment: What if the last item on which the query is built, gets deleted by a user? Would the `overviewPollsQuery` in which this deleted document was passed in `startAfterDocument()` still work and keep getting updates?