# Flutter check if stream is empty before close end

Tags: flutter, stream, rxdart

I'm using `BehaviorSubject` as a Stream controller.

In one of my functions, I want to `.add` more items only in case the Stream is empty of events.

```
  @override
  Future<void> fetchNextOverviewPolls() async {
    if (await _pollOverviewStreamController.isEmpty) return; // My Problem

    final lastDoc = await _pollOverviewStreamController.last;
    final querySnapshot =
        await _overviewPollsRef.startAfterDocument(lastDoc).limit(5).get();
    for (final doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      _pollOverviewStreamController.add(doc);
    }
  }
```

The [isEmpty](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-async/Stream/isEmpty.html) property returns a value in case the Stream ends. I want to check it when the Stream is still running.

How do I do that?

Comment: something like this? `Stream<T> addOtherIfParentIsEmpty<T>(Stream<T> parent, Stream<T> other) async* {
var empty = true;  
await for (final item in parent) {
yield item;
empty = false;
}
if (empty) {
yield* other;
}
}` - i dont understand what you really mean by: *"I want to check it when the Stream is still running."*

Comment: Is something like this possible? `final controller = StreamController<int>();
  controller.add(0);
  if (controller.stream.isEmpty) { // <-- is that possible?
    controller.add(1);
  }
  controller.close();`

Comment: Issue solved, `BehaviorSubject` supports `hasValue`. @pskink appreciate your help. I have another issue if you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72214735/flutter-bloc-firestore-pagination-using-multiple-querysnapshot-listeners-streame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BehaviorSubject](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html) supports [hasValue](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject/hasValue.html).

In the above case, use this line instead:

```
if (_pollOverviewStreamController.hasValue) return;
```